# Bower does not sync dist folder in project dependencies?

Tags: github, bower, bower-install

When I synchronize bower components via github my bower_components apps is missing dist folders and the only solution is to uninstall package and install it again.

Is it any way to build all dependencies project and got those folders?

I know that maybe removing bower_components from .gitignore is not the best approach but I try to involve my sister in development and she always has issues running a project.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by "synchronize bower components via github" ?

Comment: Thank you, sorry for ambiguity - English is my second language :-).

Here is my .gitignor


    node_modules
    dist
    .tmp
    .sass-cache
    .idea/*

So I removed 
  app/bower_components in order my dependencies can be uploaded to github

Comment: @drorb Sorry for formatting but you got the idea. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the info in the comments it looks like your `.gitignore` file is causing git to ignore the dist directories.
I suggest reading [Checking in front-end dependencies](http://addyosmani.com/blog/checking-in-front-end-dependencies/) before deciding whether to commit your bower_components to git.

Comment: Oh, mine God... it was a mental eclipse. I have a dist folder in the second line of .gitignore and why it does not work? 

Thank you, drorb :-). I read the article and I agree that in most cases bower install and npm install are the better choice but when you have a beginner in your team and she lives in another time belt you ask in the morning - is it ready? No, app does not work...but time has passed.

Answer (score 2):

Well,

I wanted to comment on drorb's post but apparently I don't have much of a rep :) You rock. nodejitsu looks at .gitignore and I was commenting out dist instead of /dist. It was essentially ignoring files that were within and bower_component that had a /dist/ directory.

Comment: If you work in Webstorm install .gitignore plugin, it really helps.